# How to prove that $m_a^2+m_b^2=5m_c^2$

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I want to prove the formula $$m_a^2+m_b^2=5m_c^2$$ for a right triangle whit c the median of the hypotenuse. I find it this formula in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry) and I want to prove it. If you can, please use easy steps to prove it, I'm 9th class ( I don't know the US educational system). Thank you so much

Comment: thank you Matti P. Can I ask you how to write formulas here in Stack Exchange as you did it?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: @Beautiful_Physics I suppose you meant to write in your question that $\;c\;$ is the hypotenuse and $\;m_c\;$ is the median to the hypotenuse...didn't you?

Comment: Yes DonAntonio, and by the way, yes the median $m_c$ is not perpendicular to the hypothenuse

Comment: @Beautiful_Physics Yes, I know it isn't in the general case...that's what I commented in the 2nd answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any triangle $ABC$ we have  $$m_a=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}.$$
Thus, since $m_c=\frac{c}{2}$, we need to prove that
$$2b^2+2c^2-a^2+2a^2+2c^2-b^2=5c^2$$ or
$$a^2+b^2=c^2,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Using Pythagorean Theorem
$$m_a^2=b^2+(\frac{a}{2})^2$$
$$m_b^2=a^2+(\frac{b}{2})^2$$
$$m_a^2+m_b^2=5(\frac{a^2+b^2}{4})$$
$$c^2=a^2+b^2$$ and length of median to hypothenuse is $$2m_c=c$$